# WSOIS 5.1 roles as comma separated list

Tags: wso2-identity-server

WSO2 IS 5.0 returned SAML response with all roles in single AttributeValue as comma separated list. Now the WSO2 IS 5.1 returns all roles as own AttributeValue's.

Is it possible to get 5.1 to return roles as comma separated list in single AttributeValue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

In Identity Server 5.1.0, it returns each role separately like below in the SAML response.

```
        <saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/role"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >admin</saml2:AttributeValue>
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >Internal/everyone</saml2:AttributeValue>
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >role2</saml2:AttributeValue>
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >role1</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
```

However, in IS 5.0.0, it was returning the roles in a single attribute as comma separated values like given below.

```
        <saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/role"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >admin,Internal/everyone,role2,role1</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
```

In IS 5.1.0, if you want to get the same behavior that retrieving all roles together, you have to add following property to the particular userstore configuration. (two commas).

```
<Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,,</Property>
```

If it is the primary userstore, you can add it to user-mgt.xml file. If it is a secondary userstore, you can add this property to the particular configuration file in repository/deployment/server/userstores/ location.

I have explained this in the blog post [1].

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/09/saml-multi-valued-attributes-in-wso2.html

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. This solved my problem :)